# External USB SSD not recommended for full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Peter Wiulle said:

> Don't use an external drive connected through USB - such hardware is
> not designed for the kind of heavy database load Bitcoin Core causes.

Why is that? Im using a Samsung T7 2TB on the USB 3.0 port, is a 16 core CPU, super fast. I have not seen problems using my Linux distro of choice and it was fully synced but now im worried. What could go wrong?

I bought this because in case I wanted to travel I could easily plug the drive on other computer. Also I don't use that setup for anything but to run the node so it seems convenient. It would just be so annoying to run this on a mounted SSD.